# Pass data to NSMutablearrays between two viewControllers, IOS 4.3

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

I am trying to pass an object in NSMutablearray  to another view's NSmutableArray

I have been looking related question but couldnt figure out whats wrong.

my view switches correctly but it doesnt pass the object in my NSmutable array

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    StartHuntViewController *startHuntController = [[StartHuntViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartHuntView" bundle:nil];
    startHuntController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:startHuntController animated:YES];;
    startHuntController.forStandButton = [stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];// doesnt work
   // startHuntController.standLocation.text=[stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // this works
    [startHuntController release];

    [self.mytableView reloadData];
}
```

view i am trying to pass data is

```
.h file
@interface StartHuntViewController : UIViewController<UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,CoreLocationControllerDelegate> {


    NSMutableArray *forStandButton;


}
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSMutableArray *forStandButton;
.m file

@synthesize forStandButton;
```

what should i do ? i guess there is nothing wrong with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed assign to retain,  move the line `startHuntController.forStandButton = [stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    StartHuntViewController *startHuntController = [[StartHuntViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartHuntView" bundle:nil];
    startHuntController.forStandButton = [stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    startHuntController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:startHuntController animated:YES];
    [startHuntController release];
    startHuntController =nil;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

there are many issues here, for first look :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSMutableArray *forStandButton;
```

why property is not retain?

Comment: i was using retain first then i try to use assign without knowing what assign exactly does but problem was i was passing the data after view transion all i needed to was move problem line two lines up

Answer (score 0):

You need to use retain in the property statement. Since `forStandButton`  is a property of the second view, you want to make sure it is getting set. If you create a setter (`setForStandButton`) for it, you can put a break point in the setter method. Once  you have confirmed that the setter is being called, make sure it is being retained long enough to be useful.

Comment: i change it to retain and  put a break point line **startHuntController.forStandButton = [stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];** in log first i see **forStandButton NSMutableArray  0x0  ** then when i start to compile it goes  @synthesize and it becomes  **forStandButton NSCFString  0x4e73260** and value ** becomes_value NSCFString * 0x848de80** that means does it try to pass it?

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, but apparently what you were seeing is a case where the new view is loaded before you set the property. I am guessing that you needed this property to be initialized before the view was fully set up. This could be the case if you finish setting up your second view in the viewDidLoad method of its view controller (which is the right thing to do).